# How to jump to static function definition from its calling point?

Tags: c, static, ctags

I have a C source file, where some static function declarations and definitions are both present. I used `ctags -R` to generate tags file. When I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> on this static function call, then ctags is taking me to the static function *declaration*, not the static function definition. I want ctags to take me to static function *definition*. Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: This sounds editor dependent.

Comment: I make prototype because static function is called before it is defined.

Comment: A [mcve] please.

Answer (score 2):

use " ctags -uR " .
then use " cscope -uRC ".
Enter the function name at " Find this global definition : "
you will get the function defination .